# Mobile only, all JavaScript, all textual, call now button

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have created the following mobile only, all textual (no image files and also no non-UTF8-characters), all JavaScript call now button which I have tested and works.

```js
let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (viewportWidth < 480) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <aside class="all_textual_cnb_wrapper">
        <a class="all_textual_cnb_link" href="tel:PHONE_NUMBER">Call now ✆</a>
    </aside>
    `)
    
    newStyle = document.createElement("style");
    newStyle.type = "text/css";
    newStyle.innerHTML +=`
        .all_textual_cnb_wrapper {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
            padding: 0 0 5px 0; /* vertical-centralization fix */
            font-size: 36px;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #149714;
        }
    
        .all_textual_cnb_link {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .all_textual_cnb_link:hover {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .all_textual_cnb_link:active {
            color: red !important; /* fix a collide with MediaWiki */
        }
        .all_textual_cnb_link:focus {
            color: #fff;
        }
    `;
    document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
} else {
    console.log("No mobile call now link");   
}
```

**How would you review it?**